# Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in on line 9

Tags: php

im really new on programming....i cant figure out where the problem is....is there anyone to help me please? TIA!!!

```
<?php
$_SESSION['username']= $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password']= $_POST['password'];
//here it comes the line 9
if (isset($_SESSION['username']== "magister") && isset($_SESSION['password']== "signum"))
{
    header("location:teacher.php");
}
else
{
   if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password']))
   {
      header("location:student.php"); 
   }
}
```

Im trying to do my login...I also need to do more validations right?

Comment: You may want to read on up the PHP manual site about what `isset` is used for, and what goes inside. You have an expression, which is not allowed. You need to instead just check like `isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] == 'magister'`

Comment: You have to have `session_start();` at the top of all pages using sessions.

Comment: i forgot to paste it, but i have a session_start() at the top!!! tks!!

Comment: Why are you checking if it's set? You just assigned the variables on the previous lines.

Comment: isset will not really help in this case, since you are setting the vars already on line 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand first what `isset()` does. Here's what it does : it checks whether the argument supplied to it is **set**. It will return `false` if the argument is not defined.

In your case, I think you want to check if the post data is set or not. For that you need to check this first:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    // rest of the code
}
```

After that you will compare if the username and password matches and then redirect the user to the particular page.

Here's the code

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) { 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password']; 
    if ($_SESSION['username'] == "magister" && $_SESSION['password'] == "signum") { 
        header("location: teacher.php"); 
    } else if($_SESSION['username'] == "something" && $_SESSION['password'] == "somethingElse") {
        header("location: student.php"); 
    } else {
          // redirect somewhere else like to login.php
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, as I said, Im still studying( and by myself), not easy at all.,im gonna try to do that, !!!.

Comment: Yes I understand. There's no problem in asking. Anyways, if you think that your problem is solved, please mark this answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use isset() function twice. because isset () function is used to check whether a variable is set or not. so just remove the other isset() function

```
    <?php
      $_SESSION['username']= $_POST['username'];
      $_SESSION['password']= $_POST['password'];
      //here it comes the line 9
      if ($_SESSION['username'] == "magister" && $_SESSION['password']== "signum")
      {
           header("location:teacher.php");
      }
      else
      {
          header("location:student.php"); 
      }
```

Comment: missing brackets or is that you intended? (isset($_SESSION['username'] == "magister" && $_SESSION['password']== "signum")???

Comment: how  you expect this to work isset($_SESSION['username'] == "magister" && $_SESSION['password']== "signum")

Comment: TechGenz Hosting, I tried to do that alerady, and I still have the message:Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)...  :(

Comment: Just remove the isset() function you don't require that function.